# Do not match if character is within a character repeat of length N or greater

Tags: regex

I want to match each instance of character `c` that is **not** within a contiguous repeat of `c` that is `N` or more characters long.

In my case the character to match, `c`, is `"` and the number of repeats, `N`, is 3. Specifically, I want to know a single regex solution for matching a lone `"` character and both characters in `""`, but no characters in `"""`. For the sake of my task it's easiest to do this with a few separate patterns, but I'm curious in learning a solution that'll teach me more about regex. It would be great if the solution could scale for values of `N` greater than 3.

In this example, `N=3` and `c="`:

```
 "OK" 
 "" 
 """OK"""
```

The first four instances of `"` should be the only matches (no `"` on the third line should match).

The closest I've come is from using negative lookbehinds/lookaheads: `(?<!"{2})"(?!"{2})`. This doesn't exclude the character in the middle of the repeated stretch however. It doesn't scale for other values of `N` either.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `\"{1,2}` or `\"\"?`

Comment: Are you trying to match the text within the quotes? The whole line? or just the quotes?

Comment: Sorry I should have used another character as an example. I was trying to match just the quotation marks and nothing more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds, but you need to look for "anything that's not a quote", surrounding the expression you allow for a quote:

```
(?<!")""?(?!")
```

For the more general case where you want between M and N quotes, and M > 1 or N > 2, use

```
(?<!")"{M,N}(?!")
```

Comment: Had I looked at your answer earlier I wouldn't have offered mine (now deleted), as yours is so clear and direct. A minor point: you might want to write `"{1,2}`  rather than `""?` to emphasize its generality and avoid the need to count double-quotes when `N = 85`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. I made the suggested update. While my solution is simpler and probably runs faster, yours wins on sheer novelty value. I wasn't being sarcastic when I said it's neat. You don't need to delete your answer. The comment you added is more than sufficient.

Comment: I understood your meaning and agree that it's a neat technique. I too enjoy seeing answers that may not represent the best way to solve the problem at hand but are interesting and educational. That's the case with most highly complex regular expressions you see at the forum. Often an alternative approach that employs a few lines of code would be a more sensible solution (and certainly easier to test). I think I'll leave my answer buried this time, however, as the gap between mine and yours is just too great.

Comment: Wow thank you both! Great answer!

Comment: @James. I'm glad it worked out for you.